# Add Login page from mysql database to swift

Tags: mysql, swift, xcode9

I'm trying to implement a website's login database to a swift app but I can't seem to find how to do so, all of the things I find online don't really help. The website stores the login data in a mySQL database and I want to implement that into my app.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class SignInViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet var UsernameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var PasswordTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var LogInButton: UIButton!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    // Remove Autocorrection Type
    UsernameTextField.autocorrectionType = .no
    PasswordTextField.autocorrectionType = .no
    PasswordTextField.textContentType = UITextContentType("")
    //Next button takes user to the next textfield
    UsernameTextField.delegate = self
    PasswordTextField.delegate = self
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@IBAction func LogInButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
// `READ VALUES FROM TEXTFIELDS
    let username = UsernameTextField.text
    let password = PasswordTextField.text

// CHECK IF BOTH FIELDS ARE EMPTY
    if (username?.isEmpty)! && (password?.isEmpty)! {
// DISPLAY ALERT MESSAGE HERE
        print("User name \(String(describing: username)) or password \(String(describing: password)) is empty")
        displayMessage(userMessage: "Both fields are required to fill in")

        return
    } else if (password?.isEmpty)! {
        displayMessage(userMessage: "You did not enter a passwords")
        return
    } else if (username?.isEmpty)! {
        displayMessage(userMessage: "You did not enter a username")
        return
    }
// CREATE ACTIVITY INDICATOR
    let myActivityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray)
// POSITION ACTIVITY INDICATOR IN CENTER OF THE VIEW
    myActivityIndicator.center = view.center
// START ACTIVITY INDICATOR
    myActivityIndicator.startAnimating()

    view.addSubview(myActivityIndicator)



 }


func displayMessage(userMessage:String) -> Void {
    DispatchQueue.main.async
        {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: userMessage, preferredStyle: .alert)

            let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in
                // Code in this block will trigger when OK button tapped.
                DispatchQueue.main.async
                    {
                        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
            alertController.addAction(OKAction)
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion:nil)
    }
}

//Remove keyboard on tap of screen and Go to next textfield everytime user taps on next
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if textField == UsernameTextField{
        PasswordTextField.becomeFirstResponder()

} else if textField == PasswordTextField {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
    return true
  }
func removeActivityIndicator(activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView)
{
    DispatchQueue.main.async
        {
            activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            activityIndicator.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}

}
```

How do I add the login information from the mysql database into the application? My objective here is to create an app for the website where I can use the same username and password as the one of the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to create an API service for the app to send the username and password and your backend validate if the login is valid.
Look into REST/JSON services.

Comment: How do I create an API service? I'm not very advanced in swift.

Comment: The API is not done in swift. you need your backend to develop an endpoint that validates the login information and only when that's available you will be able to make swift connect to it and do your login through the app. http://www.restapitutorial.com/

Comment: One other thing you can look into is using social media login (facebook, google) and use their service to validate your login, but you will still need some sort of connection to the backend to store tokens and other stuff

Comment: Can you tell me how to create the API and ten call it in the swift project

Comment: @moesafar is not that simple. The API depends on the backend language you are using, it involves connecting to database, security, etc.. etc.. etc... I would recommend googling more about it as this is not a simple task. Please select my answer as it answers your main question.

Comment: Okay thanks. The backend language in my case is php right?